# how to check that const array members grow monotonically at compile time

Tags: c++, constexpr, constexpr-function

assume we have const array:

```
const int g_Values[] = { ... };
```

how check that members grow monotonically at compile time, i.e. `g_Values[i] < g_Values[i + 1]`

in runtime this possible to check like this:

```
bool IsMonotonously()
{
    int i = _countof(g_Values);
    int m = MAXINT;
    do 
    {
        int v = g_Values[--i];
        if (v >= m) return false;
        m = v;
    } while (i);
    return true;
}
```

but how rewrite this with constexpr and if `IsMonotonously()` return `false` - generate compile time error.

Comment: You can use std::is_sorted https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted

Comment: @vladyslav, is this at compile time?

Comment: @ILS as it's marked as `constexpr`

Comment: Please don't add solutions to the question. If you have a new solution that is not already posted, you can post an answer yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is impossible for an array that is just `const`. You need to make it `constexpr` to be able to use it in a constexpr context.

All you need to do in addition to this is to implement the function for checking the array as `constexpr`:

```
template<class T, size_t N>
constexpr bool IsStrictlyMonotonouslyIncreasing(T (&arr)[N])
{
    bool result = true;

    if (N > 1)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; result && (i != N - 1); ++i)
        {
            result = (arr[i] < arr[i + 1]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

const int g_Values[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
static_assert(IsStrictlyMonotonouslyIncreasing(g_Values)); // compiler error g_Values is not usable in a constexpr context

constexpr int g_Values2[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
static_assert(IsStrictlyMonotonouslyIncreasing(g_Values2)); // ok
```

Comment: @ArminMontigny Can you point me to the compiler where this fails? Note: I'm assuming c++20 and gcc, clang and msvc seem to accept it: https://godbolt.org/z/6jExqPG4T also the loop breaks the first time we identify 2 neighboring indices that are different, so no need for `&=`, check the condition in the `for` loop again.

Answer (score 1):

Fantastic answer is given already. Just as an additional note:

Starting with C++20, several functions in the algorithm library have now also a `constexpr` implementation. This includes `std::adjacent_find`. And this also in the "ranges" version.

The solution to your problem is nearly given in the cpp reference [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/adjacent_find) with using `std::ranges::adjacent_find`.

The example uses `std::ranges::greater` as the predicate which would allow for repeating values, resulting in none-strict ordering.

So, we need to use [std::ranges::greater_equal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ranges/greater_equal). This will also deduce the parameter types of the function call operator from the arguments automatically, which makes live a little bit easier.

The code could look something like the below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>
namespace rng = std::ranges;

template <typename T, size_t N>
constexpr bool increasingValues(T(&a)[N]) noexcept {
    return (rng::end(a) == rng::adjacent_find(a,  rng::greater_equal()));
}
constexpr int arr[] = { 10, 20, 20, 40, 50};

static_assert(increasingValues(arr), "Array values are not increasing");

int main() {
    std::cout << *(std::end(arr) - 1)<< '\n';
}
```

---

With Microsoft Visual Studio, the editor would already show the problem.

And the compiler would generate 2 messages with a clear hint.

```
Static assertion failed with "Array values are not increasing"
```

Please see a screen shot below:

[image]

---

---

---

.

.

.

By the way, the accepted answer compiles like the below

[image]

And with fixing to `constexpr`, we can see:

[image]

Comment: Could you add the error messages from the first screenshot as text? The red squiggly line makes it clear enough where the error comes from, but the actual text of the message is hard to read.

Comment: Thanks. I actually meant for it to be added to the answer itself so that future readers could see it, not just for myself. I've added it in now.